# Laravel - all is_current is updated even when checkbox is not checked

Tags: laravel

I am working on a web application using Laravel-5.8. In the project, when I perform a store action or perform an update action, I have been able to set all other is_current to 0 apart from the newly created or updated one.

```
public function create()
{
  return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.create');
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalIdentityRequest $request)
{
  $identity = AppraisalIdentity::create([
    'appraisal_name'  => $request->appraisal_name,
    'appraisal_start' => $appraisalStart,
    'appraisal_end'   => $appraisalEnd,
    'is_current'      => $request->has('is_current'),
]);
    $id = $identity->id;
    // this line update all column to 0 and leave $id field
    AppraisalIdentity::where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['is_current' => 0]);

  Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is created successfully');
  return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}

public function edit($id)
{
  abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_edit'), 403);
  $identity = AppraisalIdentity::where('id', $id)->first();

  return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.edit')->with('identity', $identity);
}

public function update(UpdateAppraisalIdentityRequest $request, $id)
{
abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_edit'), 403);

$appraisalStart = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_start);
$appraisalEnd = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_end);
$submissionStart = Carbon::parse($request->submission_start);
$submissionEnd = Carbon::parse($request->submission_end);

$identity = AppraisalIdentity::find($id);
$identity->appraisal_name = $request->appraisal_name;
$identity->appraisal_start = $appraisalStart;
$identity->appraisal_end = $appraisalEnd;
$identity->is_current = $request->has('is_current');
$identity->save();

 AppraisalIdentity::where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['is_current' => 0]);

 Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is updated successfully');
 return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}
```

However, I have this observation, even when the checkbox (is_currrent) is not checked, my code still set all other is_current to 0. This should only happen when the checkbox is checked.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It is due to conditions you are using, you are skipping current id and updating rest.

Comment: @Prashant - Prashant.  How do I resolve it?